# Variance within each cluster

Tags: r

I have done some clustering to a matrix with 30 random variables , each variable has 13000 observations ). i got 10 clusters

and now i need to test how good the clustering is by calculating the variance in each cluster.
does anyone knows how can i calculate the variance?

i can easily calculate the variance of each column in my matrix (e.g the variance of each random variable) but i want to calculate the variance of the whole cluster.

does anyone know how it can be done?

e.g.

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,3,7),
               y=c(30,40,40,30,10),
               z=c(1,2,3,4,5),
               cluster=c('a','a','c','a','c'))

candidates <- dlply(data,.(cluster),function(data){
 laply(data[,-4],var)
})
```

This gives variance per column for each cluster label (a,c). I don't think it's the right approach.

Comment: this feels a bit more like a statistical question than a programming question.  What is your definition of "total variance"?  Do you want to allow for correlation among the columns?  The sum of squared Mahalanobis distances (see `?mahalanobis`) might be a sensible metric ...

Comment: I realised the same so I just posted it on cross validated. I want to know what should be the approach for calculating the variance in this multivariate dataset. Should I compute the Centroid mean for each cluster group and use it to calculate variance for that cluster group?

Comment: This is exactly what I would do - one of the definition of variance being $\sigma = \srqt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_i (x_i - mean)^2}$.